# Sending multiple duplicate PUT requests

Tags: javascript, react-native, put, expo

part of this app I'm working on for class is supposed to be scanning the barcode of a book (using the expo XDE barcodescanner component) and then sending the scanned barcode to a database that another group in my class is handling. My issue right now is that every time I do a scan, I see in my console that I'm sending multiple duplicate PUT requests. I think the problem is that the expo barcodescanner doesn't just scan once and then stop, but keeps on scanning, and each time it scans, my state is "updated" and component is re-rendered. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can modify my code to make sure that I'm not re-rendering over and over again with the same data? I've included the relevant code below. Note: some of the data is hard-coded for testing purposes. Thank you!

```
class SecondScreen extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state= {
        results: []
    }
    this.fetchData = this.fetchData.bind(this);

  }

  fetchData(URL) {
    return fetch(URL)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseData) => {
        return responseData 
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error)
      })
  }


_handleBarCodeRead = data => {
    let isbn = data.data; 
    let URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:' + 
    isbn;


    this.fetchData(URL).then(bookResult => {

      this.setState({ results: bookResult }

      fetch('https://p0kvnd5htd.execute-api.us-east- 
           2.amazonaws.com/test/return', {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({

        'libraryName': 'lib1', //libName
        'bookBarcode': '18263' //isbn
      }),
    })

      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status == 400) {
          console.log(response.status)

          alert('Return unsuccessful, please try again.');
        }
        else {
          console.log(response.status)
          this.props.navigation.navigate('ThirdPage', { title: 
          this.state.results.items[0].volumeInfo.title });
        }
      })
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <BarCodeScanner
        onBarCodeRead={this._handleBarCodeRead}
        style={[StyleSheet.absoluteFill, styles.container]}
      >
        <View style={styles.layerTop} />
        <View style={styles.layerCenter}>
          <View style={styles.layerLeft} />
          <View style={styles.focused} />
          <View style={styles.layerRight} />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.layerBottom} />
      </BarCodeScanner>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy fix would be to use lodash's [debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#debounce) function:

command line:    `npm i lodash`

top of javascript:

```
import _ from 'lodash'
```

wrap _handleBarCodeRead in debounce, this will prevent _handleBarCodeRead from being called multiple times for 3 seconds after the last call:

```
_debouncedHandleBarCodeRead = _.debounce((data) =>{ this._handleBarCodeRead(data) }, 3000, {leading: true, trailing: false});
```

change BarCodeScanner to used the debounced method:

```
<BarCodeScanner onBarCodeRead={this._debouncedHandleBarCodeRead} >
```